# Bootstrap 4 accordion for navigation in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, angular2-routing

I want to create nested menu with json object in Angular 4. I have written below code.

```
<div id="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let mainItem of objectKeys(my_menu); let i = index">
    <div class="panel-heading" (click) = "current = i">
      <h5 class="panel-title">{{ mainItem }}</h5>
    </div>
     <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse" [class.collapse]='current != i'>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let subItem of my_menu[mainItem]"><a href="#">{{ subItem }}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  current: number = 0;
  items: Array<any>;

  objectKeys = Object.keys;
   my_menu = {
    'Menu 1': ['Sub Menu 1', 'Sub Menu 2'],
    'Menu 2': ['Sub Menu 1', 'Sub Menu 2', 'Sub Menu 3'],
    'Menu 3': []
  };
}
```

Here is my working example [My example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cl3dtc). My problem is now how to check menu have sub menu and how to add router link and how to check have submenu or not. Please help

Comment: Your logic almost correct. But you should not use spaces for a property name- the preferered notation is camelCase, make it menu1, menu2, menu3 . Then the iteration can easily corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reorganise the object as per our need and do implemention.

```
my_menu = [
    {menu:[{main:'Menu 1', submenu: [{sub:'Sub Menu 1', route:'/home1'}, {sub:'Sub Menu 2', route:'/home2'}]}]},
    {menu:[{main:'Menu 2', submenu: [{sub:'Sub Menu 1', route:'/about'}, {sub:'Sub Menu 2', route:'about1'}, {sub:'Sub Menu 3',route:'about2'}]}]},
    {menu:[{main:'Menu 3', submenu:[]}]}
  ];
```

Refer for [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d-mxhv3x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse" [class.collapse]='current != i'>
```

The logic is not correctly done. However if you remove the condition check `[class.collapse]='current != i'` This will fix your issue. Nothing else is needed.

Comment: Hi @Anoop can you please help me. I'm new in angular that's why I am facing problem

Comment: Sure I will work on the stackblitz link you provide, and contact you soon

Comment: Thank you so much :) Here is link what I have tried so far. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cl3dtc

Comment: Updated answer please check . Hope that this is what you expected

Comment: To add router link Please explain the context. Is all those submenus to be routed to a same page or different page, no reference is given